# DAX - count the number of consecutive values (groups) in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, cluster-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with two columns, one listing dates, one listing one or zero.  For example:

```
Date |Val
1-Jan   0
2-Jan   0
3-Jan   1
4-Jan   1
5-Jan   1
6-Jan   0
7-Jan   0
8-Jan   1
9-Jan   1
10-Jan  1
11-Jan  1
12-Jan  1
13-Jan  0
14-Jan  0
15-Jan  0
16-Jan  1
17-Jan  0
18-Jan  1
19-Jan  0
20-Jan  0
```

I am trying to create a measure which calculates the number of groups (clusters) of ones in the dataset.  In this case the answer should be four.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit.

I have managed to create something that, with a measure of good will, could be considered a DAX measure and it is working but it's certainly not elegant and I'm sure there is a better way of doing it:

```
var ClusterStart = ADDCOLUMNS(
    'Table',
    "Cluster Start",
    var PreviousNumber =  CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Val] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table'),
            'Table'[Date] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date])-1
        )) return

    if(AND('Table'[Val]=1,PreviousNumber<>1),1,0)) return

SUMX(ClusterStart,[Cluster Start])
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution to me. I would remove EARLIER and use a VAR instead but otherwise looks fine.

Comment: @DavideBacci what do you mean by "use a VAR"?

Comment: I'll add an answer to explain so you can see the DAX.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Using EARLIER() is practically deprecated and it is now preferable to use VAR to make the code easier to read. The following returns the same as your code for example.

```
Clusters = 
VAR ClusterStart = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        'Table',
        "Cluster Start",
        VAR d = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date]))
        VAR PreviousNumber =  
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Table'[Val] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table'),
                'Table'[Date] = d-1
            )
        ) 
        RETURN
        IF(AND('Table'[Val]=1,PreviousNumber<>1),1,0)) 

RETURN
SUMX(
    ClusterStart,
    [Cluster Start]
)
```